# How to pass a datetime parameter from Entity Framework SqlQuery and SqlParameter to a Stored Procedure?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, datetime, sqlparameter

This is my code on server:

```
model.Grid.DataSource =
       db.Database.SqlQuery<Reports.Cardex>("[dbo].[SP_RptCardexSummary_English_1] @OwnerCode, @TypeCode, @MeasurementUnitCode, @FDate",
       new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@OwnerCode", Value = filterList[0] },
       new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@TypeCode", Value = filterList[1] },
       new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@MeasurementUnitCode", Value = filterList[2] },
       new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@FDate", Value = filterList[3] })
       .ToList();
```

and my procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_RptCardexSummary_English_1] 

@OwnerCode int,
@TypeCode int,
@MeasurementUnitCode smallint,
@FDate datetime
```

UPDATE:
I created a DateTime value by String:

```
var date = "2015/05/25";
var time = "20:30"
filterList.Add(Convert.ToDateTime(date + " " + time));
```

But when I pass a `System.DateTime` value, it throws an exception:

> "The specified cast from a materialized 'System.DateTime' type to the 'System.String' type is not valid."

How should I pass it?
And interesting thing is, when I set SQL Profiler for observing and run what SQL Profiler received, It works fine!! What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops! I found out... ridiculously I forgot to change the type of one of my return data from `string` to `Datetime`!

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot happening in this one line of code.

On the way down you are sending in a datetime to a datetime parameter.

The error message is a problem converting a date to a string. Could this be on the way up? Are you trying to send a date into a string on the datagrid?

You should start by creating a unit test that executes the stored procedure.

Comment: yea... you'r right! I miss that, but I updated it. Could you take a look again?